# Ошибка подключения модуля в Nuxt 3 приложение

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite

При сборке для разработки всё работает хорошо. Но если собирать production билд, то появляется ошибка.

Ошибка: `"custom-vue-scrollbar" is imported by ".nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/[chunk].js", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.`

Подключаю так:
*plugins/scrollbar.ts*

```typescript
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import CustomScrollbar from 'custom-vue-scrollbar';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp: any) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('custom-scrollbar', CustomScrollbar);
});
```

Использую так:
*app.vue*

```html
<template>
  <custom-scrollbar>
    <NuxtPage />
  </custom-scrollbar>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь что вы правильно все импортируете)

*plugins/scrollbar.ts*

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import CustomScrollbar from 'custom-vue-scrollbar';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp: any) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('custom-scrollbar', CustomScrollbar);
});
```

*nuxt.config.ts*

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/scrollbar', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

Помните, что подключаемые модули могут не поддерживать SSR, поэтому необходимо прописывать, чтобы они работали на стороне клиента, удачи!)